# Groovy + OSGi or Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, osgi

I have been learning OSGi and also a little about Groovy recently but am very new to both.  I know Groovy is part of the Grails framework and that Grails is good for rapid development.  One of the most desirable features in OSGi is class loader management and I believe this is probably still an issue with Grails (correct me if wrong).  So, I'm curious is it possible, or even desirable to run Groovy and/or Grails in an OSGI environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [Grails plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/osgi) available, that turns a Grails application into an OSGi bundle that can be deployed on SpringSource's dm server. The plugin author has also posted some [blog posts](http://blog.jetztgrad.net/grails-on-osgi/) about the integration of Grails with OSGi. However, as far as I understand, the OSGi support of the Grails framework is still rather limited and will be "natively" supported with [Grails 2.0](http://grails.org/Roadmap).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, there is no real benefit in packaging your entire application as an OSGi bundle, except that you can run it in a OSGi container. It will not make your application more modular, because it is still one big bundle. Note that using OSGi will not simplify anything with regard to class loading. It can introduce problems when you are using libraries which have not been designed to run in an OSGi environment. Don't use it unless you have a good reason to do so. It is a great technology, but it will not make anything simpler or better by just dropping it in.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to think, that the other way around is more preferable: let Grails modules, like GORM or GSP run in an OSGi container. 
All Groovy or Grails jars (which are modules rather than plugins now) are already OSGi-compatible, so it shouldn't be a problem to install them into a running container. Thus you can combine the advantages of both ecosystems.

On the other hand, deploying an app packaged as a huge monolithic bundle into a OSGi container doesn't make much difference compared to tomcat.